# How to get deeper with recursion to take all sub-categories

Tags: php, recursion

Basically, I need to make a tree structure from categories and their children. For this purpouse I tried to make it with recursive method this way:

```
public function getCategoriesTree($idRootCategory = null)
    {
        $this->db->select("gc.*");
        $this->db->from('glami_categories gc');
        $this->db->where('CATEGORY_PARENT_ID', $idRootCategory);

        $categories = array();

        foreach ($this->db->get()->result_array() as $item) {
            $children = [];
            $subcats = $this->getChildren($children, $item['CATEGORY_ID']);
            $item['children'] = $subcats;
            
            $categories[] = $item;
        }
        return $categories;
    }

    private function getChildren(&$children, $parent_id)
    {
        if (!$parent_id) {
            return $children;
        }
        $subcats = $this->db
            ->select("*")
            ->from('glami_categories')
            ->where('CATEGORY_PARENT_ID', $parent_id)
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
        if ($subcats) {
            if (isset($children[$parent_id])) {
                $children[$parent_id]['children'][$subcats[0]['CATEGORY_ID']] = $subcats[0];
            } else {
                $children[$subcats[0]['CATEGORY_ID']] = $subcats[0];
            }
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                $paretn_sequence[] = $parent_id;
                return $this->getChildren($children, $subcat["CATEGORY_ID"]);
            }
        }
        return $children;
    }
```

But like this I am getting up to level 2 of the category tree and not even all records. It goes pretty messy in other words. For testing purpose I will upload the whole table here (because it has 700+ rows and pasting it in the body of the question will be pretty ugly) [table data](https://pastebin.com/qajQR4bf)
In conclusion I am interested in what is my mistake in the recursion and how to improve it to get the desired result. Thank you!

**EDIT**
The correct result is structured this way:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["CATEGORY_ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["CATEGORY_NAME"]=>
    string(39) "Дамски дрехи и обувки"
    ["CATEGORY_FULLNAME"]=>
    string(39) "Дамски дрехи и обувки"
    ["CATEGORY_PARENT_ID"]=>
    NULL
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      [180]=>
      array(5) {
        ["CATEGORY_ID"]=>
        string(3) "180"
        ["CATEGORY_NAME"]=>
        string(23) "Дамски дрехи"
        ["CATEGORY_FULLNAME"]=>
        string(76) "Glami.bg | Дамски дрехи и обувки | Дамски дрехи"
        ["CATEGORY_PARENT_ID"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          [184]=>
          array(4) {
            ["CATEGORY_ID"]=>
            string(3) "184"
            ["CATEGORY_NAME"]=>
            string(10) "Рокли"
            ["CATEGORY_FULLNAME"]=>
            string(89) "Glami.bg | Дамски дрехи и обувки | Дамски дрехи | Рокли"
            ["CATEGORY_PARENT_ID"]=>
            string(3) "180"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

E.g. if the category has children, new key `children` must be set and the key of each child is its `CATEGORY_ID`.

Comment: What's your quesiton about this? Where exactly is the given code not working as expected? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: It's all in the question above. My code is in the begining but you probably didn't even tried to understand what is the problem. Like it is said, the deepest level of subcategories is not reached. The example I gave in the end is just a example of how the structure have to look. If you just came to act like some smart guy with "Whats your question", you can go forward.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug **why** the deepest level is not reached?